# Reference request: variation of global section of line bundle over curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g > 0$ over an algebraically closed field. Suppose $r > 2g - 2$. Then given $r$ points $(P_1, \cdots, P_r) \in C^g$, Riemann-Roch implies that $l(P_1 + \cdots + P_r) = r + 1 - g > 0$.

**Question**
Can
$$L(P_1 + \cdots + P_r) \to (P_1, \cdots, P_r)$$
be made into a vector bundle over $C^r$? If not, are there special cases where it is indeed a vector bundle?

Thank you!

Comment: The more natural way to do this is that $\operatorname{Sym}^r C$ is a $\Bbb P^n$-bundle over $J(C)$, the Jacobian of $C$. See [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68687/symmetric-powers-of-a-curve-projective-bundle-over-jacobian-and-the-relative) for some details.